# CakePhp Naming convention. Why it works?

Tags: php, cakephp

Yes, i understand mvc pardigm, but i want know how exactly it handle in CakePhp?
I have a model Category and if i follow naming conventions my controller will be Category**s**Controller.
But it wrong in terms of spelling and CakePhp handle it and i can call my controller CategoriesController.

1) How it works?

2) What happens if i have both of this controllers? They bounded with 1 model?

I found nothing about this question in cakebook =\

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: No, if you follow conventions it should still be CategoriesController (you have to plurarize the model name, not just put an s behind it) and that should work, as Cake's pluralizer translates "y" to "ies" (generally speaking).

Comment: Oh, thanks, so i need explore Inflector.. i think...

Comment: Yes, you can use http://inflector.cakephp.org/ to see it in action. For example: http://inflector.cakephp.org/Category . Also note "smart" pluralizations like http://inflector.cakephp.org/Person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake handles the inflections using regular expression rules. The rules take into account most general rules for pluralising words in English and even handles irregular words like 'ox' (plural: 'oxen') and 'person' (plural: 'people'). You can find the rules in the `lib/Cake/Utility/Inflector.php` class. They're quite easy to read, but you can also test the inflector using this [handy tool](http://inflector.cakephp.org/).

If you have the controllers `CategoriesController` and `CategorysController` these will both default to using the `Category` model as both 'Categories' and 'Categorys' inflect to the singular 'Category'. If you actually had both of these controllers in your app it shouldn't cause an issue as you can have multiple controllers linked to a model; it would just be a little confusing in the code.